# spl autoloading: Class is not found – namespace issue?

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I am just getting my feet wet with PHP autoloading. I actually think I got the basics down, but somehow it still won't work.

I got the following directory structure:

```
myLib
    -bootstrap.php
    -sven
        -project
            project.php
```

`bootstrap.php` is the file that will be included to use the lib. In this file, I simply have the following code:

```
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

$var = new \sven\project\project();
$var->init();
```

And in `project.php`:

```
namespace sven\project;

class project {
    public function init() {
        echo 'It works!';
    }
}
```

The way the autoloader is used, to my understanding, the core PHP autoloader should translate the namespace into directories and then look for a php containing the class.

Instead of displaying 'It works!', a fatal error is thrown. Unfortunately, I can't exactly tell what that error is because the CMS only informs me that there was a fatal error.
But with such a simple structure, I am sure the error is pretty basic and easy to find for someone who knows how it works.

Where am I going wrong with this example – did I correctly describe how the autoloader should work in this setup or is there a misunderstanding?

EDIT: Finally got the error log running:

`Fatal error: Class undefined: sven\\project\\project\\project\\project in /xxx/bootstrap.php on line 36`

That obviously looks wrong, but how to change that? Why are there two backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```

This code works only with PHP 5.3 and above.

Comment: Well, I am running 5.6.99 & hhvm 3.3.0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sven,

I just answered another question about spl_autoload, try my example [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200010/php-autoload-with-namespace/30514130#30514130)

I hope it helps!

PS:
Also don't just autoload all .php files on your path , that can be dangerous !